# python: dedup and count a given list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, duplicates

I am using the following code to dedup and count a given list:

```
def my_dedup_count(l):
    l.append(None)
    new_l = []
    current_x = l[0]
    current_count = 1
    for x in l[1:]:
        if x == current_x:
            current_count += 1
        else:
            new_l.append((current_x, current_count))
            current_x = x
            current_count = 1

    return new_l
```

With my testing code:

```
my_test_list = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d']
my_dedup_count(my_test_list)
```

result is:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)]
```

The code is doing fine and the output is correct. However, I feel my code is quite lengthy and am wondering would anyone suggest a more elegant way to improve the above code? Thanks!

Comment: A multiset viz. `collections.Counter` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't re-invent the wheel. Use the standard library instead; you want to use the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
from collections import Counter

def my_dedup_count(l):
    return Counter(l).items()
```

You may want to just return the counter itself and use all functionality it provides (such as giving you a key-count list sorted by counts).

If you expected only consecutive runs to be counted (so `['a', 'b', 'a']` results in `[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1)]`, then use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def my_dedup_count(l):
    return [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(l)]
```

Comment: I'll leave this here as comment for the rare case where someone wants to avoid importing `collections`: `[(e,my_test_list.count(e)) for e in set(my_test_list)]`

Comment: @vmg: that's very, very inefficient, as that will fully traverse `my_test_list` K times (where K is the number of unique elements), making that a O(KN) algorithm (where N is the length of the input list). There are more efficient ways of doing this even without a `Counter()` (although the counting code in `collections.Counter` is highly optimised).

Comment: @vmg this creates the set in every *iteration*. you can at least store it in a variable and use the variable in the comprehension

Comment: @vmg: and `collections` is part of the standard library, why would you want to avoid importing from that?

Comment: Martijn: yes, indeed. Ev: no, it's created once

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two versions of some shorter ways to write what you accomplished.

This first option ignores ordering, and all like values in the list will be deduplicated.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def my_dedup_count(test_list):
    foo = defaultdict(int)
    for el in test_list:
        foo[el] += 1

    return foo.items()

my_test_list = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d', 'a', 'a', 'd']
>>> [('a', 4), ('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('d', 2)]
```

This second option respects order and only deduplicates consecutive duplicate values.

```
def my_dedup_count(my_test_list):
output = []
succession = 1
for idx, el in enumerate(my_test_list):
    if idx+1 < len(my_test_list) and el == my_test_list[idx+1]:
        succession += 1
    else:
        output.append((el, succession))
        succession = 1

return output

my_test_list = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d', 'a', 'a', 'd']
>>> [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('a', 2), ('d', 1)]
```